# Convert Numbers file to Excel file

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, conversion, iwork-numbers

I have a spreadsheet created on a Mac using the software "Numbers".
In which way can I convert it into an Excel file to modify it on a Windows pc?

Comment: You can't natively. Your choices are 1) to get them to save it as excel rather than Numbers or 2) find a 3rd party conversion tool [recommendations for which would be off-topic for Super User unfortunately] ... or a late 3) moan at Microsoft. Numbers can read & write Excel format, Excel should be able to read & write Numbers... :/

Comment: Just search Google for "numbers to xls" and take the top hit, for goodness sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open that Numbers file in Mac and select "File > Export To > Excel…" from menu.